# Imported openVDB sequence from another scene moves around randomly

Tags: import, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

Like the title says, I did a smoke sim in another scene and tried to import the vdb sequence to a new one and the whole volume moves about semingly randomly, please help im ripping my hair out over here!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly it's known bug. :(

https://developer.blender.org/T79711

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the adaptive domain and how to origin is imported

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for adding the solution to your Q. Could you expand on it please so that future seekers can learn from your solution too? Thanks :)